# RDkit and PySmiles results differ on some SMILES strings

Tags: python, rdkit, smiles

I recently started using both `pysmiles` and `RDkit` to parse `SMILES` strings into molecules. However, I sometimes got different results between the two libraries.

For example, on the molecule described by the string `OCCn2c(=N)n(CCOc1ccc(Cl)cc1Cl)c3ccccc23`, which is parsed using `RDkit` into the following molecule:

[image: SMILES string converted to molecule by RDkit]

This molecule has some atom such that `RDkit`'s `atom.GetNumImplicitHs()` gives a value of $0$, while `pysmiles`  `hcount` attribute for these atoms is $1$.

This also happens for other molecules, and also with the formal charge value I have seen a similar problem.

Why does this happen? How can I know which library is "right"? Or maybe I didn't understand correctly those features (I'm no chemist, so excuse me for that)? Thanks!

For completeness, the code I used to process the SMILES string with each library is shown below:

- RDkit: `molecule = RDkit.Chem.MolFromSmiles(smiles)`
- pysmiles: `molecule = pysmiles.read_smiles(smiles)`

Comment: How are you reading in the SMILES string with each program? They will classify hydrogens as implicit/explicit depending on the options passed to these functions.

Comment: Using `RDkit`, this is the code: `molecule = RDkit.Chem.MolFromSmiles(smiles)`, and for `pysmiles` this is what I use: `molecule = pysmiles.read_smiles(smiles)`. I don't have any additional options that I passed to them

Comment: is the pysmiles you are talking about the graph-to-smiles program on github? If so i’m wondering why you are using this like this.

Comment: This is the library im using: https://pypi.org/project/pysmiles/

Comment: Also, I'm converting *from* smiles *to* a graph, and not vice-versa

Comment: Can you point out a specific atom in the structure where the values don't match (or all of them if there are multiple cases)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a bug in pysmiles.

pysmiles has problems with aromatic nitrogen if the SMILES is in aromatic form (lower case) but not if it is kekulized (upper case and double bonds)

If we add the hydrogens to the molecule, the nitrogens on index 3 and 6 have none, because they have already three bonds.

```py
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem.Draw import IPythonConsole
from rdkit.Chem import Draw
import pysmiles

s1 = 'OCCn2c(=N)n(CCOc1ccc(Cl)cc1Cl)c3ccccc23'  # aromatic
s2 = 'OCCN2C(=N)N(CCOC1=CC=C(Cl)C=C1Cl)C3=CC=CC=C23'  # kekulized


def show_implicit_h(smiles):
    m = Chem.MolFromSmiles(smiles)
    for atom in m.GetAtoms():
        atom.SetProp('atomLabel', str(atom.GetIdx()))
    m = Chem.AddHs(m)
    return Draw.MolToImage(m, size=(300, 300))


show_implicit_h(s1)
```

[image: aromatic]

```
show_implicit_h(s2)
```

[image: kekulized]

Counting the hydrogen on both smiles shows that pysmiles finds hydrogen in the aromatic, but not in the kekulized SMILES.
RDKit finds none in both.

Columns: Index, Symbol, hcount pysmiles, hcount RDKit

```py
def count_implicit_h(s):
    m = Chem.MolFromSmiles(s)

    mol = pysmiles.read_smiles(s)
    hc = mol.nodes(data='hcount')

    for n in hc:
        print(n[0],
              m.GetAtomWithIdx(n[0]).GetSymbol(), n[1],
              m.GetAtomWithIdx(n[0]).GetNumImplicitHs())
```

aromatic form (`count_implicit_h(s1)`):

```
0 O 1 1
1 C 2 2
2 C 2 2
3 N 1 0
4 C 0 0
5 N 1 1
6 N 1 0
7 C 2 2
8 C 2 2
9 O 0 0
10 C 0 0
11 C 1 1
12 C 1 1
13 C 0 0
14 Cl 0 0
15 C 1 1
16 C 0 0
17 Cl 0 0
18 C 0 0
19 C 1 1
20 C 1 1
21 C 1 1
22 C 1 1
23 C 0 0
```

kekulized form (`count_implicit_h(s2)`):

```
0 O 1 1
1 C 2 2
2 C 2 2
3 N 0 0
4 C 0 0
5 N 1 1
6 N 0 0
7 C 2 2
8 C 2 2
9 O 0 0
10 C 0 0
11 C 1 1
12 C 1 1
13 C 0 0
14 Cl 0 0
15 C 1 1
16 C 0 0
17 Cl 0 0
18 C 0 0
19 C 1 1
20 C 1 1
21 C 1 1
22 C 1 1
23 C 0 0
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks! Its sad to know that pysmiles had a bug all along :(

Answer (score 8):

Speculating a comparison of the outputs by both programs may help, I let `RDKit` process to SMILES to yield a representation including the atom indices.  Derived from the [cookbook](https://www.rdkit.org/docs/Cookbook.html#include-an-atom-index), the MWE for the Jupyter notebook was

```
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem.Draw import IPythonConsole
from rdkit.Chem import Draw
from rdkit.Chem import rdDepictor
from rdkit.Chem.Draw import rdMolDraw2D

from IPython.display import SVG
IPythonConsole.ipython_useSVG=True  


def mol_with_atom_index(mol):
    for atom in mol.GetAtoms():
        atom.SetAtomMapNum(atom.GetIdx())
    return mol


mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles("OCCn2c(=N)n(CCOc1ccc(Cl)cc1Cl)c3ccccc23")
mol = mol_with_atom_index(mol)
mc = Chem.Mol(mol.ToBinary())


drawer = rdMolDraw2D.MolDraw2DSVG(450, 200) 
drawer.DrawMolecule(mc)
drawer.FinishDrawing()

svg = drawer.GetDrawingText()
display(SVG(svg.replace('svg:','')))
```

In a second step, I requested `pysmiles` to list for non-H atoms atom index, atom symbol (first two columns) and number of hydrogen bound (trailing column).

```
from pysmiles import read_smiles

smiles = "OCCn2c(=N)n(CCOc1ccc(Cl)cc1Cl)c3ccccc23"
molecule = read_smiles(smiles)

pysmiles_list = zip(molecule.nodes(data="element"), molecule.nodes(data="hcount"))
for element in pysmiles_list:
    print(element)
```

By visual inspection, RDKit's annotated formula and pysmiles' listing agree with each other *except* for the endocyclic nitrogens (`N:3` and `N:6`):
[image]

```
((0, 'O'), (0, 1))
((1, 'C'), (1, 2))
((2, 'C'), (2, 2))
((3, 'N'), (3, 1))
((4, 'C'), (4, 0))
((5, 'N'), (5, 1))
((6, 'N'), (6, 1))
((7, 'C'), (7, 2))
((8, 'C'), (8, 2))
((9, 'O'), (9, 0))
((10, 'C'), (10, 0))
((11, 'C'), (11, 1))
((12, 'C'), (12, 1))
((13, 'C'), (13, 0))
((14, 'Cl'), (14, 0))
((15, 'C'), (15, 1))
((16, 'C'), (16, 0))
((17, 'Cl'), (17, 0))
((18, 'C'), (18, 0))
((19, 'C'), (19, 1))
((20, 'C'), (20, 1))
((21, 'C'), (21, 1))
((22, 'C'), (22, 1))
((23, 'C'), (23, 0))
```

A similar listing of atom index, atom type, and number of hydrogens bond to the non-H may be achieved iterating with RDKit over the non-H atoms

```
for atom in mol.GetAtoms():
    print("{:2} {:2} {}".format(atom.GetIdx(), atom.GetSymbol(),
                                atom.GetTotalNumHs()))
```

to yield

```
 0 O  1
 1 C  2
 2 C  2
 3 N  0
 4 C  0
 5 N  1
 6 N  0
 7 C  2
 8 C  2
 9 O  0
10 C  0
11 C  1
12 C  1
13 C  0
14 Cl 0
15 C  1
16 C  0
17 Cl 0
18 C  0
19 C  1
20 C  1
21 C  1
22 C  1
23 C  0
```

---

As outlined in the answer by `@rapelpy`, there is a problem with pysmiles which the maintainer(s) might rectify in future. The computations in this answer were performed with [pysmiles](https://pypi.org/project/pysmiles/) (version 1.0.1, Jun 25, 2020), and [RDKit](https://rdkit.org/) as packaged for [Debian 11 (testing)](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/rdkit) (version 2020.09.4).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help! I didn't quite get where I see the number of hydrogens that `RDkit` calculated here. Where is it shown?

Comment: Its only implicitly present, in the structure drawing. I wasn't sure if the atom indices used by RDKit and PySmiles would align; the map annotated by atom indices side by side to the listing now suggest they do.

Comment: Hmm. How can I be sure that they align for all my data, without checking for a few examples and just hoping it won't do problems?

Comment: The Phonopy room has now been changed into the "[python-based software room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112358/python-based-matter-modeling-software-phonopy-pysmiles-pyscf-etc)" since it wasn't very active before, and questions like this which are about a python software like PySmiles not matching with the output of RDKit, can benefit from having a room when the discussions in comments get long.

Comment: @nirshahar continuation at https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58750154#58750154

Comment: The atom with index 3 here is exactly what I asked about in the question. RDkit says there is no hydrogen, but pysmiles says there is. Who is right? What should I trust?